# indexing server in windows 2008 is not indexing all files

Tags: windows-server-2008

im trying to index a folder that has some 2k pdf files. But it's not indexing 6 files. i copied those 6 and created a new catalog. it indexes.

what could be wrong. i tried emptying the catalog and reindex it. still it's not indexing all files.

Pls help. this is windows server 2008.

-Vivek

Comment: what permissions are on the 6 files, I'm assuming they are the same as all the others but...

Comment: same as all others...

Comment: i had 2k files. it indexed 1989 files. then i deleted teh catalog and recreated it. it indexed 1994 files. again i deleted and recreated it indexed 1993 files. it's more than 12 hrs. still the 7 files are not indexed. waht could be wrong. this is jsut a sample. I ahve other catalog where 2000 files are not indexed. we moved from 2000 environment from 2008. in 2000 all files are indexed. whereas in 2008 we have these issues. pls help

Comment: what pdf filter are you using adobe or foxit?

Answer (score 0):

One trick to force re-indexing: remove the folder from the catalog, add a different folder, let the indexing begin (Monitor Docs to Index column), stop it, remove the folder and then add back your original folder.